# How to list git tags with the dates of the original commits

Tags: git

I want to list git tags along with the dates of the commits they are pointing to (not the dates when the tags were created). I also want to sort them by the dates of the original commits in reverse order.

For example, I have 3 commits created on `Aug 1`, `Aug 3` and `Aug 5`. **Later** I've created 3 tags pointing at these commits. All tags were created at `Aug 10` so they all have the same date.

I want the following (sorted by commit dates in reverse order):

```
tag-1.2     Aug 5       
tag-1.1     Aug 3       
tag-1.0     Aug 1
```

I've tried to use `committerdate`, but it seems to be empty, and the commits are not sorted:

```
git for-each-ref --sort=-committerdate --format "%(tag) %(committerdate)" refs/tags

tag-1.0     
tag-1.1     
tag-1.2
```

`taggerdate` works, but it is the date when the tag was created, not the original commit:

```
git for-each-ref --sort=-taggerdate --format "%(tag) %(taggerdate)" refs/tags

tag-1.2     Aug 10      
tag-1.1     Aug 10      
tag-1.0     Aug 10
```

Comment: I tried to reproduce your second attempt (with committerdate), but oddly enough I don't have the same output at all. The sort by commit date is fine but the tag names don't show up. I'll be curious to know why. Thanks for your interesting question.

Comment: Are you sure about your syntax? Shouldn't `--sort=-committerdate` be `--sort=committerdate` instead? (without the dash) And isn't an equal sign expected instead of a space after `format`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isn't that the [example mentioned in `git for-each-ref`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-for-each-ref#_examples), using the '`*`' notation?

> If fieldname is prefixed with an asterisk (`*`) and the ref points at a tag object, **use the value for the field in the object which the tag object refers to** (instead of the field in the tag object)
>
> Show the most recent 3 tagged commits:

```
vonc@voncav:/mnt/d/git/git$ 

git for-each-ref --count=3 --sort='-*authordate' --format='%(*authordate) %(*refname)'

Thu Jun 21 10:00:06 2018 -0700 refs/tags/v2.18.0^{}
Wed Jun 13 12:57:07 2018 -0700 refs/tags/v2.18.0-rc2^{}
Mon Jun 4 21:41:41 2018 +0900 refs/tags/v2.18.0-rc1^{}
```